# Close Native Host when Chrome is closed by the user

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am working on a Chrome extension that uses a C++ Native Host. In a background.js script (persistent set to false), using chrome.onstartup event, I create the connection to the C++ Host.

I want my Host to be running for as long as the user is actively using Chrome.

If I close all my current Chrome tabs, independent Chrome processes still appear in the "Background section" of the Task Manager (including my Host process that must be explicitly killed).

I understood that the user can configure the Chrome not to run background processes, but can I design my extension to kill the Host process(disconnect the port) when the user closes all Chrome tabs?

Moreover, the problem becomes more serious if I disable the extension. The Host process becomes a detached process in the background. If enable the extension again, kill all Chrome processed and restart Chrome (as my extension connects to Host on startup of Chrome), I will have multiple Host processes.

Comment: Sounds like you may have specified `"permissions": ["background"]` in which case you can detect the last window being closed in chrome.windows.onRemoved listener. OTOH maybe you can remove that permission so the port will be closed automatically. If it still doesn't that may be a bug in Chrome which you can still circumvent, but it'll be hackish.

Comment: I added the permission ['tabs'] and created 2 event listeners. One that fires when new windows are created, it has a callback function that connects to the Host if the port is null. The other listener fires when windows are removed and last window should disconnect the port (call port.disconnect() on the global variable port). I follow the logs and everything seems in the right order, however when I open Task Manager, the Host process is still alive (on its own). Am I correctly disconnecting the Host?

Comment: Are you listening for messages from Chrome? Chrome will send `-1` to your native messaging host before it terminates. So you will have to check if the char value equals to -1, if it is then do termination work

Comment: Thank you @Asesh for your answer. You are right, when the Chrome process gets killed, it sends "-1" instead of the 4 bytes signifying the length of the message. I didn't see this specified anywhere. I added a special case in the Host for negative length that exits the while loop in which the host continuously waits for extension messages (therefore the Host process terminates). Thank you again!

Comment: Glad it helped. I have posted that answer below so that it will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 2):

When Chrome terminates or your extension is unloaded, it will send `-1` message to your native messaging host. You will have to check for that value, assuming your native messaging host is written in C++ then this is what you should do:

```
int read_char = ::getchar();
if (read_char == -1) {
// Do termination work here...
}
```

Comment: Where is the documentation for that?

Comment: @mohamed I don't think it's documented any where, I found it while debugging our native messaging host

Comment: Hmm, that's good but how did you capture it. I use my native host to save all messages sent from extension into a txt file but never saw -1 in the file

Comment: Like I said before, I used debugging to find the value returned

Comment: i mean how do you make the debugger interact with the extension. when i debug using vstudio, the output portion in always empty (no interaction). but the extension is interacting with another instance of the exe

Comment: We have our native messaging host app written in C++. Just set a breakpoint in that code and attach a debugger to your app. As soon as Chrome exits or your extension is unloaded, it will send that message to your extension