# Multiple native app are ran by connecting with native messaging when reload the extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

In chrome extension, I use native messaging to call the local application. But I found an issue that everytime I reload the extension, it seems like a new process is created for the application. By the documentation, the app will be ended if the `port` is disconnected or the page is closed. Does that mean reload extension won't close the `background` page? How can I solve this problem? Also, I cannot find my local application process in the chrome task manager.

```
// background.js

var port = null;
connectToNativeHost();

// Receive message from other js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log("background recieved message from " + sender.url + JSON.stringify(request));
        parseMessage(request);
    }
);

//onNativeDisconnect
function onDisconnected()
{
    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    console.log('disconnected from native app.');
    port = null;
}

// Receive message from native app
function onNativeMessage(message)
{
    console.log('recieved message from native app: ' + JSON.stringify(message));
}

//connect to native host and get the communicatetion port
function connectToNativeHost()
{
    var nativeHostName = 'com.group_project.time_tracker';
    port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(nativeHostName);
    port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
    console.log("connected");
}

// Send message to native app
function sendMessage(message)
{
    port.postMessage(message);
    console.log('send messsage to native app: ' + JSON.stringify(message));
}
```

Comment: Assuming you're looking at the `Processes` tab in the task manager, not in the main tab, it means there are actually no multiple processes. Reloading an extension terminates the old background page context and runs it again. When it uses connectNative, the host app starts again. The old one should be autoterminated as the documentation says.

Comment: I checked Windows task manager and Chrome task manager. Currently, I just wrote a system tray icon to indicate the running application, and I am pretty sure that there will be the same number of icons as the number of clicks of "reload"

Comment: There's an ancient bug in Windows which is still present that when a process is killed its tray icon stays so this is not a reliable indicator at all. There are probably some methods to clean it up in your app, maybe run a second process, I don't know, google it up. Also you need to check the Windows task manager's Processes tab as I mentioned in my first comment. Certainly not Chrome's task manager.

Comment: You might want to look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55079220/close-native-host-when-chrome-is-closed-by-the-user It's your job to close your application, Chrome won't do it.