# Chrome Native Messaging exit NodeJS host when the extension is unloaded or uninstalled

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have a NodeJS native host for a Chrome extension which spawns python processes. 
When I uninstall the extension, the node process isn't terminated.

From the answer here: [Close Native Host when Chrome is closed by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55079220/close-native-host-when-chrome-is-closed-by-the-user) Chrome should send '-1' to the Host.
Where should I listen for this data?

I use an example from here: https://github.com/simov/native-messaging

And this is the code:

```
process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
    var input = []
    var chunk
    while (chunk = process.stdin.read()) {
      if (chunk===-1) {
sendMessage({message: 'python', body: 'exiting'});
        process.exit();
      }
      input.push(chunk)

    }
    input = Buffer.concat(input)

    if (Buffer===-1) {
      process.exit();
    }
//sendMessage({message: 'python', body: Buffer});
 //console.log('\u0007');

    var msgLen = input.readUInt32LE(0)
    var dataLen = msgLen + 4

    if (input.length >= dataLen) {
      var content = input.slice(4, dataLen)
      var json = JSON.parse(content.toString())
      handleMessage(json)

      if (json===-1) {
        process.exit();
      }


    }
  })
```

I've tried to check for this '-1' value everywhere, but the process still doesn't exit.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should read that message via `stdin`, that's where Chrome will send that message

Comment: @Asesh I'm using `process.stdin.on('readable', () => {`. Is this correct? I'm logging this to a file, and when I close the Chrome Extension, there is nothing in that file. What am I doing wrong?